# IntelliJ IDEA VCS rules to fail commit

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control

Is it possible to setup IDEA to prevent index of being commited if code matches some criteria, for example contain some special comment like `//failcommit` ?

IDEA warns you on commit if there is `//todo` or `//fixme` comments in modified files. I'd like to config something similar but instead of warning it should block commit action at all.

Comment: Not that I know of. You could use a CI technique and branching to achieve broadly the same thing though.

Answer (score 3):

How about having git do the commit check and failure, instead of intellij? Then it doesn't matter what IDE you are using. If that is acceptable then you could set up a git pre-commit hook that fails if the target comment is found.

Git hooks documentation: https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Example pre-commit hook that fails if 'FIXME' is found anywhere: https://gist.github.com/kuy/5d1151fd5897a9b84c06

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Will try to do it this way. Do you know how IDEA handle these hooks ?

Comment: IDEA issues a git command, and git itself runs hooks by default (unless you explicitly disable Run GIt hooks option in IDEA). Most hooks should work unless they operate index.

Answer (score 2):

There are no settings in IDEA to configure this. You could develop your own CheckinHandler to do this, and add it to the Before commit section.

The question is why do you need this? Why the warning that allows you to cancel commit is not an option? You could just configure a custom pattern for TODO.

Using git hooks is another option.

BTW, IDEA does not commit index. It commits individual files, using `git commit --only`

Comment: Answer to your question `why do you need this?` is most probably because of wrong approach that we have atm. `TODO` and `FIXME` comments are usually used in order to mark a thech debt so it should be committed and handled later. As a result skipping warning dialog become a habit (bad habit). But at some point in order to resolve a blocker (for day or two until someone on backend fix it) we have to do some really dirty hacks that should not be committed any way. That's the case when I'd like to mark that hack to prevent commit.

Comment: I would go with git hooks then